# error in match() function of javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, match

I been doing a filter of employee name, I use match() in comparing the array of name and the input of the user.

[image]

Here is my code in matching

```
filteredEmp = [];

filterEmployee(name){

 let len = this.employeesList.length;

 for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    if (this.employeesList[i].name.match(name)) {
        this.filteredEmp.push(this.employeesList[i]);
    }
 }
}
```

but when I input a name like this

```
name = 'Min';
```

the output is different

```
this.filteredEmp =[ 

         0:{id:1,name:"Casper, Mika"},
         1:{id:1,name:"Casper, Mika"},
         2:{id:3,name:"Ming, Edmund"}

]
```

expected output should be like this

```
this.filteredEmp =[ 

     0:{id:3,name:"Ming, Edmund"}

]
```

I'm using angular 2 so if you have a suggestion that could help me in my filter please do so.

Comment: What does `employeesList` look like?

Comment: match is used with a regular expression as the first argument. you're providing a string. Try to use `Array.prototype.indexOf` or `Array.prototype.find`

Comment: it just the same with this.filteredEmp but only contains filtered employee

Comment: I think you're looking for `includes`. `match` is for regular expressions.

Comment: You really should show the actual code..... I have a feeling there is a simple explaination if we saw the real code, not the invalid code shown.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to correctly return just the one expected result:

```js
// Added
let employeesList = [
{
  'name': 'Casper, Mika'
},
{
  'name': 'Ming, Edmund'
},
{
  'name': 'Someone, Else'
}
];

filteredEmp = [];

function filterEmployee(name) {
  let len = employeesList.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (employeesList[i].name.match(name)) {
      filteredEmp.push(employeesList[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(filteredEmp);
}

//filterEmployee('Mi'); // Matches 'Mika' + 'Ming'
filterEmployee('Min'); // Only matches 'Ming'
```

I can only assume that you accidentally typed `filterEmployee('Mi')` instead of `filterEmployee('Min')`, which would also be a match against `Mika`.

To do a case-insensitive search, simply replace the `name` in `.match()` with `new RegExp(name, 'i'))`, adding the case-insensitive modifier.

```
if (employeesList[i].name.match(new RegExp(name, 'i'))) { }
```

This can be seen in the following:

```js
// Added
let employeesList = [
{
  'name': 'Casper, Mika'
},
{
  'name': 'Ming, Edmund'
},
{
  'name': 'Someone, Else'
}
];

filteredEmp = [];

function filterEmployee(name) {
  let len = employeesList.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (employeesList[i].name.match(new RegExp(name, 'i'))) {
      filteredEmp.push(employeesList[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(filteredEmp);
}

filterEmployee('min');
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: how about in lowercase what should I do then

Comment: ^ I'm not sure what you're asking. You just filter based on what you enter for `name`.

Comment: I filter (min) but the result give an empty array

Comment: To do a case-insensitive search, you can simply replace `name` in the `.match` with `new RegExp(name, 'i'))`, to add the case-insensitive modifier. I've updated my answer to showcase this.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong function. `String.prototype.match` is expecting a regular expression at the first argument.

You need `String.prototype.indexOf`:

```
filteredEmp = [];

filterEmployee(name){

 let len = this.employeesList.length;

 for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    if (this.employeesList[i].name.indexOf(name) > -1) {
        this.filteredEmp.push(this.employeesList[i]);
    }
 }
}
```

or better use array functions instead of iterating over it by yourself:

```
filteredEmp = [];

var filterEmployee =(name)=>{
    this.filteredEmp = this.employeesList.filter((empName)=>empName.name.indexOf(name)>-1);
}
```

Comment: how about in lowercase what should I do then

Comment: I filter (min) but the result give an empty array

Comment: @MariaJen First of all: Your code works also: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/v6L4s0ce/) Second: just use the `String.prototype.toLowercase` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you put 'M', 
then

```
this.filteredEmp =[ 

      {id:1,name:"Casper, Mika"},
      {id:1,name:"Casper, Mika"},
      {id:3,name:"Ming, Edmund"}
];
```

then you got error for some other reason.